# How can a methyl cation exist without 8 valence electrons?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electronic-configuration

So far I have been taught that everything wants to achieve noble gas configuration - 8 electrons in the outer shell.

I came across a methyl cation. Which contains a positive carbon, no lone pairs and 3 bonding pairs of electrons so 6 electrons in total. 6 electrons are obviously less than 8 electrons so how can it exist as it defies apparently the rules I have been taught.

Comment: Some say humans can't fly. In fact they can, but not for long. Same thing here.

Answer (score 2):

Methyl cation certainly *does* exists. What matters about such ions/radicals is how long could they exist stably or alternatively, in what ways and what extent can they be stabilized.

Methyl cation, $\ce{CH_3^+}$ has a sextet of electrons which is not a big problem in its existence. But it is short lived because the extra positive charge is localised in carbon and has no means of either dispersal or diminish it. This makes it short-lived.

But secondary carbocation ($\ce{R_2CH^+}$) gets two alkyl groups to draw electrons from them and be relatively more stable. Tertiary carbocation ($\ce{R_3C^+}$) can draw electrons from all the three alkyl groups and hence is the longest lived and so the most stable.

Please note that **noble gas configuration** is a widespread rule but not a universal rule. [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/methyl-group) asserts that methyl cation is a *transient intermediate* so it will eventually constitute a compound after reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Some stable molecules exist without $8$ electrons in the outer shell, like $\ce{NO}$ (or $\ce{ClO2}$). Of course they dimerize at rather low temperatures. But at room temperature and usual pressures, these molecules exist and are stable.

Answer (score -1):

The way you put it that *everything wants to achieve noble gas configuration* is a good rule of thumb for predicting molecules that are stable and long-lived. However, not everything is in equilibrium. A methyl cation certainly exists, and it certainly *wants* to achieve the noble gas configuration, but it still takes time to do so. So we can conclude that the methyl cation is an unstable, short-lived, highly reactive molecule, which is true. And you are totally right to explain this with the tendency of having a closed electronic shell.

Comment: Requiring every atom to simultaneously have a noble gas configuration does not always work.  Cyclopropenyl cation doesn't have that when you draw the Lewis structure(s), the anion does; yet it is the cation which (at least if chilled slightly) is indefinitely stable.

Comment: Methyl cations are not unstable by their lonesome but are reactive. Evaluation of stability requires a reaction.